# Использование libxml2 в Qt проекте

Tags: c++, qt, library

Работаю в Qt 5.7 на Windows 10 . Понадобился html парсер, клонировал репозиторий libxml2 и действовал по инструкции в конце [этой статьи](http://web.archive.org/web/20150129024748/http://blog.sjinks.pro/c-cpp/qt/942-html-parser-qt/). Только в INCLUDEPATH вписал += D:\Projects\libxml2\include .Но во время компиляции возникает ошибка

> D:\Projects\libxml2\include\libxml\xmlstring.h:15: error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory

Как решить данную проблему?

libxml2 качал [отсюда](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html) , точнее тупо последовал инструкции

> git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43201/discussion-on-question-by----libxml2--qt-).

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы склонировали git репозитарий, вы получили исходники, из которых собирается конечная библиотека. В том числе генерируется отсутствующий в вашем случае файл `libxml/xmlversion.h` (который получается из `libxml/xmlversion.h.in`, он есть на вашем скриншоте).

Чтобы не разбираться в тонкостях сборки, можно скачать готовый, собранный под Windows официальный вариант по адресу:

http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Скачал, но теперь появилась другая  [проблема](http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/TALP.png) , остальные lib файлы тоже самое выдают

Comment: @АмирАфендин наверное вы lib файлы к проекту не подключили

Comment: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../win32/lib/ -llibxml2 это ли не подключение?

Comment: @AmirAfendin если либа начинается с lib, то тогда так LIBS += -L$$PWD/../win32/lib/ -lxml2